# "Ionic start" aborts: "Not starting project within existing project" although folder is empty (Ionic 5 / Node 12)

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, setup-project

I created an empty folder in where i want to create an easy starter project with Ionic (Angular-based). 
I got the feedback:

```
ionic start "My App" blank
```

> --no-confirm: You are already in an Ionic project directory. Do you really want to start another project here? No [INFO] Not starting
>   project within existing project.

I have the following dependencies installed:

OS: Windows 10

Ionic: v5.4.6

Cordova: v9.0.0

NodeJS: 12.13.0

Is there a way to create a project again with this command? If possible, i want to avoid downgrading stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, quicker find than expected. You will have to add the "--confirm"-Flag.

```
ionic start --confirm "My App" blank
```